# Date comparison in where condition in C# with oledb database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have to take 2 values from DateTimePicker and then compare their values with that in database.

Code:

```
string dt_start = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
string dt_end = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString();
string mySelectQuery = "Select * from " + out_table + " WHERE [Date] Between " + dt_start + " and " + dt_end + " ";
```

It is not showing any error, but I am not getting output values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access uses **#** for dates. This should work:

```
string mySelectQuery = "Select * from " + out_table + " WHERE [Date] Between #" + dt_start + "# and #" + dt_end + "#";
```

Comment: In VBA, you can run into problems with locale and I suspect the same may be true here. Access requires an unambiguous date such as yyyy/mm/dd, otherwise it can use US date format.

Answer (score 0):

try the following select statement:

```
string mySelectQuery = "Select * from " + out_table + " WHERE [Date] Between '" + dt_start + "' and '" + dt_end + "' ";
```